# Counting Labeled Cyclic Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I'm a grad student in Riemannian geometry. In the course of my research on a geometric problem, I found a way
to formulate a key issue as a graph theory problem that I don't
think is too challenging. I don't have any background in graph
theory or counting in general, and so I am asking for any
references, suggested strategies, leads and so on.

Let $a$ be a special character, and suppose an alphabet
$A = \{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of other characters.

How many distinct $2m$-node cycle graphs $C_{2m}$ can be formed with every other node
labeled $a$ while the remaining  nodes are labeled with any choice of
character from the alphabet with replacement?

Note: to clarify "every other", think $2m$-tuples where either (indexed from 0) the even components are all $a$ and the odd components are selected from the alphabet, else the odd components are all $a$ with the even components selected from the alphabet. The first component is always connected to the last component, and this is what I mean by "cycle". Apologies, I am not familiar with graph language, hopefully this clarifies.

To clarify whether "distinct" is supposed to be considered up to some kind of symmetry: if you imagine these "cycles" as $2m$-tuples as described, I am interested in the number of orbits under the $\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$ action by cyclic permutation (send the first component to the last, shift other components left by one). I had thought intuitively that orbits would be in bijection with these "cycle" graphs. Considering graph isomorphism seems to be an "edge" preserving bijection between vertices, this still seems true to me after reading the comments.

I am interested in the dependence of this number on $m,n$. If not
an exact formula, then I am hoping to at least find the asymptotic behavior as
$n \rightarrow \infty$ while we assume some control over $m$, like
an upper bound, "at most polynomial growth", or some other growth
limitation.

Thanks for considering my problem!

Comment: What do cyclic graph, distinct, and every other exactly mean for you? In the easiest interpretation (coloring a labelled $C_m$ such that either $0,2,...$ or $1,3,...$ are $a$ and the rest are $b$) the answer is of course $2n^{m/2}$ when $m$ is even. If you want to count only up to some symmetries (like rotation), that is essentially have an unlabelled cycle, then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma but asymptotically the answer will not be too different. Otherwise maybe write more specifically what all the notions are.

Comment: Definitely needs to say what to do with odd length cycles and whether we have a set of cycles or just one cycle.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I meant for there to be an even number of nodes. I think you have interpreted the problem as I intended, but I edited the original post for clarity. 

Does graph isomorphism not already consider graphs "up to rotation"? It seems a rotation provides a simple edge-preserving bijection between vertex sets. That is why I thought thinking of a graph may be better than orbits of $2m$-tuples under cyclic permutation. 

Burnside's lemma when looking at orbits of 2-tuples under cyclic permutation was one of my ideas, I thought the graph might make looking at orbits unnecessary.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I see now that your answer is just twice the number of ways to make an m/2-tuple out of n characters. The point of having them be a cycle graph is that some of those choices should result in the same graph, and so the answer should be smaller than this. I guess this is what you mean by the rotations. I wonder if there is a way to do this without thinking of orbits.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the clarified question correctly, the nodes labelled $a$ are just a distraction and you want to count the $n$-ary [bracelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_bracelets) of length $m$. By Burnside’s lemma, this count is

$$
\frac1{2m}\left(mN_n(m)+a(m,n)\right)\;,
$$

where

$$
N_n(m)=\frac1m\sum_{d\mid m}\varphi(d)n^{m/d}
$$

is the number of $n$-ary [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_necklaces) of length $m$ (itself obtained using Burnside’s lemma) and $a(m,n)$ is the total number of fixed points of the reflections, i.e. the symmetries not yet taken into account for necklaces. For $m$ odd, each of the $m$ reflections fixes $n^{\frac{m+1}2}$ bracelets, so $a(m,n)=mn^{\frac{m+1}2}$, whereas for $m$ even, half of the $m$ reflections fix $n^{\frac m2}$ bracelets (because $\frac m2$ pairs of opposite vertices form orbits), and the other half fix $n^{\frac m2+1}$ bracelets (because two vertices are fixed and form singleton orbits), so $a(m,n)=\frac m2(n+1)n^{\frac m2}$.

I don’t know of any other efficient way to obtain these counts.